# NSManagedObjectContext Child/Parent - Child not removing registeredObjects

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have 2 NSManagedObject contexts, one temporary and another that is primary.  The temporary context has its parent context set to the primary context.  I use them both in the following cases:

- When I create a "new" object, I create a new one with the temporary context.  If the user hits "cancel" and decides not to create the new object, I simply delete the object from the managed object context and save that context.
- If the user saves this new object, I save the temporary context and then save the primary context to persist these changes.  I use the "performBlock" methods and chain the saves, as is recommended by Apple and other Stackoverflow posts.
- If I'm editing an existing object, I keep it in the primary context during edits.  If the user hits "cancel,"  I call "rollback" on the primary context, which discards all of the changes.

In these cases, everything seems to work fine.  After the saves, the temporary context reports that it has 0 registered objects, and the primary context has an additional object.

However, there is a case where creating a "new" object includes another object which has a relationship to this new object.  So for this object, I create the new object, create the "child" object, and set it on the parent.  So there are 2 NSManagedObjects.  I perform a "save" the same way - the temporary context is saved, and then the primary is saved afterward.  The problem is that my temporary context is still stating that it has 2 registered objects after the save is completed.  The primary object also states that it has 2, and they are all displaying correctly.

I can fix this by performing a "reset" on the temporary context after performing the "save" on the temporary context.  However, this just doesn't seem right.  Why should I have to do that?  Why is my temporary context still reporting registered objects even after performing a save?

EDIT: I can also fix this by performing "refreshObject:object mergeChanges:NO" on the object from the temporary context after performing the save on the temporary context.  This seems like the *best* solution for now (until someone can explain why I need to do this or why this is happening).  My guess is that the objects are referring to each other, which is causing the objects to not release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you perform save operation on MOC, It will save the object to parent MOC of persistent store. But object will still retained by MOC in memory.

By default, the references between a managed object and its context are weak. The exception to this rule is that a managed object context maintains a strong reference to any changed (inserted, deleted, and updated) objects until the pending transaction is committed (with a save:) or discarded (with a reset or rollback).

If you feel that this object is no longer need full for current future or alarms are generated (on the fly in a memory store), you would like to trim the graph object by turning every thing into a fault using "refreshObject:object mergeChanges:NO"

Comment: It seems that performing a "refreshObject" or "refreshAllObjects" does not cause any adverse side affects to my application.  Once the "save" occurs on the primary context, my fetched results controller is notified of the change successfully (with or without flushing the temporary context).  It seems that performing the refresh is my best option.

Comment: refreshing objects, depending on your staleness interval, causes Core Data to hit the store again.  There is a performance impact when you call refresh and it should be used sparingly.  Core Data is very good at managing its own memory.  Only get involved when you have an actual performance problem.

Comment: No real performance issue yet, just trying to prevent it from occurring in the future.  I started to investigate this and change my Core Data model when using Instruments - I noticed that deleted NSManagedObjects were staying in memory.  I couldn't find any concrete evidence or documentation that stated this is expected behavior.

Comment: By default, the references between a managed object and its context are weak.  The exception to this rule is that a managed object context maintains a strong reference to any changed (inserted, deleted, and updated) objects until the pending transaction is committed (with a save:) or discarded (with a reset or rollback). see the official link for detail  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/MO_Lifecycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH31-SW1 .

Comment: because of strong reference object was still staying in memory but not in persistent store.you can mark it fault using  refreshObject:mergeChanges:

Comment: But since I'm performing a save on the child context, shouldn't the references be weak?

Comment: @CoBrA2168 Save comes under insert / update operation so the reference will be strong to child context as per rule. I have updated the rule in my answer also.

Comment: I guess I'll stop worrying about these "counts" then.  My primary context has the correct counts, which I guess is what matters.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you considered with the number of registered objects?  Registered objects is simply a list of objects that the context is aware of.  Since that context created those objects it would naturally continue to be aware of them even after the save.  Core Data does not purge objects after a save.

Reads to me that it is working as intended.

Comment: See, I wasn't sure if this was the intended behavior or not.  What makes it seem like there's something wrong is that even after performing a "delete" operation on the objects in question, the temporary context is still stating that it has those registered objects in memory.

Comment: Yes and it will keep them registered for a period of time afterwards.  Unless you have a specific reason to be accessing registeredObjects it really does not have much value in day to day operations.  It is kind of like `-retainCount` back in the day, something that sounds useful but ultimately has no value for "us" (non-Apple developers).